DC/DC converter topology identification
Can you help me to identify the converter topology in the attached schematic?
Is it a resonant converter?

It looks similar to forward converter, but without the LC filter and with 2 extra capacitor.
Working principle is 50% constant duty cycle, +5 V (and -5 V) is transferred on the secondary side and rectified. L1 and L2 is a transformer in case you are not familiar with LTspice symbols.
After the converter there is a post regulation (with an LDO) to obtain the desired voltage.
More details: the control scheme is constant duty cycle 50%, no feedback present, just a microcontroller generating the pwm to the gate drivers of the mosfets. It is used for really low power, 100 mA maximum at primary, to generate an isolated voltage. It is used to generate a positive and negative voltage for a gate driver IC.

The output could be a voltage doubler, depends on where the output ground reference is.

Yes, this is a common approach for light loads, where simply overrating the inverter suffices for protection -- or protection is ignored entirely, on the assumption that if anything fails, the whole product fails and at that point who cares.
Other examples include MAX253/MAX845/SN6501 family, many DC-DC converter modules (typical <3W modules are unregulated, though it can be tricky to tell from datasheets, when this is the case), many two-transistor self-oscillating circuits ("chopper" and Royer (saturation-commutated), but not the resonant (Baxandall) case, often erroneously labeled "Royer"), etc.
Such designs are strongly limited on maximum output capacitance, startup current, and fault conditions, as any overload is typically handled as voltage drop in the switches themselves -- or resistance (or inductance) in the transformer.  At low power levels, it's feasible for relatively small transistors (including integrated circuits) to handle this, at least for the small startup energy that such capacitors (i.e., 5V and a few 10s, maybe 100s, µF) incur.
There are also high-power applications where regulation simply isn't required: a similar circuit is regularly found in automotive power amplifiers.  In this case, startup is afforded by leakage inductance in the transformer, highly-robust transistors (ancient IRFZ46N HEXFETs or 2nd-source equivalents are a common sight), and soft starting of the controller (typically a KA7500/TL494/etc. set for fixed PWM, but ramping up slowly on startup).  Startup energy is entirely dissipated as losses in the transistors, and needless to say there's no overcurrent or fault protection; cascade failures are common on designs like this (i.e. the amplifier stage fails, shorting the output, and the supply succumbs shortly after).
Regarding the simulation, it's not clear what issues you had with it, but "removing the capacitors" will certainly not lead to useful output: the rectifier must operate into some filter capacitance, to obtain DC.  The capacitors will generally be "oversized", so that the AC voltage is forced small in relation to the AC (ripple) current flowing through them.  Notice you also must have a ground reference to the secondary side, otherwise the floating nodes creates a singular matrix (which may be solved silently by the RSHUNT parameter, or result in very slow iteration due to the near-singular matrix).
In a recent design, I needed 5V 100mA isolated, and used a MAX253, transformer and rectifier, and 22µF filter capacitor.  Much less than this, is likely to see significant voltage ripple; much more than this, simply isn't necessary or desirable.
Using instead a 1:2 transformer and voltage doubler rectifier, the ±10V output could be re-centered as +15/-5V for IGBT driving, for example.  That is, discarding the rectifier's common and taking its total output as 20V, then making a "+5V" supply with an LDO or zener shunt, and assigning that as new "ground" (source/emitter connection).
I don't know that I would say such solutions are common for gate drives (I would rather a current-mode converter, myself, and I imagine many others would as well), but it's certainly usable for that purpose.  The isolated drive affords freedom of wiring (the power circuit can have high currents -- that would otherwise cause common-mode or EMI problems with a bootstrap driver), the controller can be completely isolated from the power circuit, and duty cycle is not limited as a bootstrap driver is (anything 0-100% is accessible).  This might be important for motor drive and UPS applications, for example.

It sounds (without more information) like an open-loop full-bridge isolation stage.  If the duty cycle is fixed at 50% it's probably not resonant.  You don't say anything about the control scheme so it's impossible to tell for sure. A phase-shifted full bridge can be resonant, but there are no resonant components in this design.
It would be unusual for a high-power topology like a full bridge to be open-loop then regulated with an LDO, so more context is needed if you want more information.

Hi John, thank you for your answer. Here you can find more details: the control scheme is constant duty cycle 50%, no feedback present, just a microcontroller generating the pwm to the gate drivers of the mosfets. It is used for really low power, 100mA maximum at primary, to generate an isolated voltage. It is used to generate a positive and negative voltage for a gate driver IC. I thought it was a resonant converter because simulating it in LTspice and removing the 2 capacitors the circuit stops working
